# How to "join" two Aggregate Roots when preparing View Model?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Assume that `Book` and `Author` are Aggregate Roots in my model.

In read model i have table `AuthorsAndBooks` which is a list of Authors and Books joined by `Book.AuthorId`

When `BookAdded` event is fired i want to receive `Author` data to create a new `AuthorsAndBooks` line.

Because `Book` is an Aggregate Root, information about `Author` doesn't included in `BookAdded` event. And i cannot include it because `Author` root doesn't have getters (according to guidelines of all examples and posts about CQRS and Event Sourcing).

Usually i receive two types of answers on this question:

1. **Enrich your domain event** with all data you need in event handlers. But as i said i cannot do it for Aggregates Roots.
2. **Use available data from View Model**. I.e. load `Author` from View Model and use it to build `AuthorsAndBooks` row.

The last one has some problems with concurrency. Author data can be not available in View Model at the time `BookAdded` event is handling.

What approach do you use to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Just curious. I always thought that the root should not have any setter as all setting is done via events? However, a root can definitely have getters IMHO. Please correct me if I am wrong ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general advice, let the event handlers be idempotent and make sure you can deal with out of order message handling (either by re-queuing or building in mechanisms to fill in missing data).
On the other hand, do question why author and book are such desperate aggregate roots. Maybe you should copy from the author upon adding a book (what the f* is "adding a book", how's that a command). The problem is all these made-up examples. Descend to the real world, I doubt your problem exists.

Comment: Okay, i see that my problem is "self-made" and i'm agree that i should be real. I see that event handlers (idempotent and ordered) are working for you. This is inspire me! :) But... Look, i can correctly build all ARs in read model (in many threads and in the correct order (simply by re-queuing as you mentioned)), but then i need to build some kind of reports which spans many ARs (in spite of design correctness, non trivial model will have at least 2 ARs anyway). Maybe it worth to fight for creating such reports from stream of events, but maybe this is another consistency boundary?

Comment: What if event handlers would build only plain "snapshots" of ARs and produced snapshots are used by another consistency boundary which do all complex computation and inter-snapshots joining to produce another model inside this boundary? I'm still trying to understand how far we can go handling events to produce our read model? Where is the end of this process and when we should stop it and start using available model (produced by event handlers) to transform it to another (using Map-Reduce or SQL)? I see that i just cannot prepare all kinds of views i need, using only event handlers...

Comment: Sorry for such long comment. I'm okay if you skip them all :)

Comment: Depending on complexity you could perform (2) or use a saga-like approach where you wait for both events and transform them into a new event which in turn can be handled.

Comment: It's a matter of choice, really. Trying is the best school.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is missing some context, for example what is the user scenario that leads to this event and what is the state you are starting from?  If you were writing the BDD tests for this case, what would they look like? Knowing this would help a lot in answering your question.

How you solve the problem of relating an book to an author is domain dependent. First we are assuming it makes sense for your domain to have an aggregate for Author and an aggregate for Book, for example, if I was writing a library system, I doubt I would have an aggregate for authors, since I don't care about an author without his/her book, what I care about is books.

As for the lack of getters, it's worth mentioning that aggregate roots don't have getters because of a preference for a [tell-don't-ask](http://lucisferre.net/2010/11/28/tell-dont-ask/) style of OOP.  However you can tell one AR to do something which then then tells something to another AR if you need.  Part of what is important is the AR *tells* the others about itself rather than writing code where you *ask* it and then pass it along.

Finally, I have to ask why you don't have the author's ID at the time you are adding the book? How would you even know who the author is then?  I would assume you could just do the following (my code assumes you are using a fluent interface for creation of AR, but you can substitute factories, constructors, whatever you use):

```
CreateNew.Book()
  .ForAuthor(command.AuthorId)
  .WithContent(command.Content);
```

Now perhaps the scenario is you are adding a book along with a brand new author.  I would either handle this as two separate commands (which may make more sense for your domain), or handle the command the following way:

```
var author = CreateNew.Author()
  .WithName(command.AuthorName);

var book = CreateNew.Book()
  .ForAuthor(author.Id)
  .WithContent(command.Content);
```

Perhaps the problem is you have no getter on the aggregate root Id, which I don't believe is necessary or common.  However, assuming Id encapsulation is important to you, or your BookAdded event needs more information about the author than the Id along can provide, then you could do something like this:

```
var author = CreateNew.Author()
  .WithName(command.AuthorName);
var book = author.AddBook(command.Content);

// Adds a new book belonging to this Author
public Book AddBook(BookContent content) {
  var book = CreateNew.Book()
    .ForAuthor(this.Id)
    .WithContent(command.Content);
}
```

Here we are telling the author to add a book, at which point it creates the aggregate root for the book and passes it's Id to the book.  Then we can have the event BookAddedForAuthor which will have the id of the author.

The last one has downsides though, it creates a command that must act through multiple aggregate roots.  As much as possible I would try to figure out why the first example isn't working for you.

Also, I can't stress enough how the implementation you are looking for is dictated by your specific domain context.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, populate read model from author/book events, using reordering to handle cases, where events get out of order (view handler is within it's own consistency boundary and should handle ordering/deduplication cases anyway).

Comment: Am i correct that you stay for point #2, combined with ordering and deduplication of events? So handler of BookAdded event should query read model to get Author information?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would ask is why there are concurrency issues in the read model. If the client is sending a reference to the author aggregate inside the AddBook command, where did it get the information from? If the book and author are created at the same time, then your event can probably be enriched. Let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: AuthorAdded and BookAdded events can be very close to each other in the event stream and it is possible that these events will be handled simultaneously by eventhandlers (in case we are using multiple threads for event handlers). So BookAdded handler can be called before AuthorAdded handler, and BookAdded handler will not find information about Author in Read Model. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: If you are dealing with commands that have data from multiple aggregates at close to the same time, and those commands have no data from the read model, AND there is such complexity in your domain that you cannot order events, the only other approach I can think of would be to use a saga. Keep your book additions as long-running processes that wait until the author events have been handled in the way that you need.

Without more information it seems like your book and author domain is simpler than your needs indicate. Ask your experts how likely the situation you are trying to prevent is.

Answer (score 0):

> The last one has some problems with
>   concurrency. Author data can be not
>   available in View Model at the time
>   BookAdded event is handling.

What about "handling the event later"? So you simply put it to the back of the queue until this data is available (maybe with a limit of x tries and x time between each try).

Comment: That is a nice possible solution. Maybe i will just complicate my project introducing such solution... But anyway thank you for this hint!